# Creating a PCB - Electrical Schematic for AMIS 30543

Tags: pcb, schematics, stepper-motor, kicad

I'm working on a project and I'm at the phase of combining the components into one PCB. Right now I'm stuck trying to understand some inconsistencies with a stepper motor drivers' documentation. The stepper motor driver is the Pololu AMIS-30543.

Here is the schematic available on the product's web page.
[image: web page schematic]

Here is the schematic available on the product's datasheet.
[image: datasheet schematic]

Here is what I have so far for my electrical schematic. What I'm wanting to know is if I'm on the right track and how to address the inconsistencies between the prior two images. Thank you for your time!
[image: current progress in KiCad]

Comment: What inconsistencies are you referring to? Your schematic will be more legible if ground signals are routed in the conventional direction.

Comment: Conventional direction? My apologies, I've never done this before so I'm learning as I go. Inconsistencies like the Vbat/Vmot sections and the callouts for R2-5. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you planning on some connector and cable? If so that explains some pull-ups but you must explain why IOref is the reference and not ask us to guess.  So wrong track. if you make ANY deviations, you better have a good reason, including layout.  how do plan to attenuate CM noise and crosstalk from the coil pairs?

Comment: VBAT=VMOT=VBB... Just different ways to label a supply. Pull-up, pull-down, and current limit resistors may vary with application. If you are in a very noisy environment, you may want a lower resistance. If you are in a low power situation, you may want to go for higher resistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd fix the inconsistencies and make it a bit more readable like this:
[image]

It helps to not have to trace the wires across the schematic, placing power nets closer to their source helps.

There is also no diode and filter on VBB (and no filter)

Answer (score 0):

If by "Inconsistencies like the Vbat/Vmot sections" you are referring to these differences:

[image]

[image]

They both are reverse polarity protections. The diode is slightly simpler but will have a higher voltage drop and power loss and heat input in the PCB.

The P-FET (Q1) solution will be much more efficient (you can easily find FETs with a few milliOhm of resistance when on). D1 is there to protect the Gate of the FET.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem I see is that you need a separate pin to bring +5 volts to VDD (Pin 32). As it stands, it's floating and that's not good. And VDD of 12 volts will destroy the chip. You need 5 +/- 0.5 volts.

As for addressing inconsistencies:

1 - The 2nd schematic is apparently from a portable system, with a separate battery system to power the motors, thus the use of Vbat. Or, the company which produced that schematic habitually uses Vbat as a designator for relatively high-voltage, high-current power supply which is separate from the "ordinary" (analog signal processing/logic) voltages.

2 - R2 - R4 are simply pullup resistors which convert open-drain outputs to outputs with a defined voltage swing. The [data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/amis-30543-d.pdf) on p. 7 characterizes the outputs as being able to pull down to 0.5 volts with a current of 5 mA, so a pullup of 1 k to +5 would theoretically work - assuming you're driving something with a very high input impedance. A value of 4.7k was chosen so as to allow extra current to be pulled from the controller it's driving. It's not a magic number, and you could probably use 10 k or even 100 k, but that depends on the requirements of whatever controller you're driving. However, 4.7 k on DO is a pretty standard resistor value for SPI busses.

3 - I assume you mean R1 instead of R5, the SLA output. This is an analog output which needs to be low-pass filtered to keep glitches from confusing whatever controller is using it.